# How to make bootstrap-vue Toast component interpret HTML tag

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I would like my toast to interpret HTML tags inside the message props and without having to call the toast from the template ,

For example :

```
    this.$bvToast.toast('Lorem ipsum <b>dolor</b> sit amet', {
    title: this.$t('assetView.toastTitle'),
    autoHideDelay: 5000,
    variant: 'danger',
    appendToast: true,
    toaster: 'b-toaster-bottom-right'
  });
```

I couldn't find anything in the documentation .

Answer (score 0):

Your answer lies in the documentation, only that it's not obvious. You can form the content of the title or the message, by using VNodes.

```
const message = this.$createElement('div',
      {},
      [
        'Lorem ipsum ',
        h('strong', 'dolor'),
        ' sit amet'
      ]);

this.$bvToast.toast(message, {
   ...
});
```